# Mathematical formulation of sklearn weighted classification tree

Tags: tree, classification, scikit-learn, weighted

I'd like to weight each sample differently when growing a simple classification tree. I understand that you can specify a vector of sample weights when fitting the tree.

I'd like to know, however, what the mathematical forumltion of the impurity function is with weights. I don't see where the weights would go in various impurity measures in the mathematical formulation documentation:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#mathematical-formulation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that is how it's implemented but one can easily add (normalized) class or sample weights to the Pmk proportion formula used in Gini, Cross-Entropy etc.